# Comparing quasibinomial glms in R

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, binomial-distribution, quasi-likelihood

I have some data that are proportions that I am trying to fit a glm to. As the data are proportions someone suggested that the quasibinomial is the correct family of glm to go for. I am now trying to do the model selection. However, as R does not give AIC scores for quasi models I'm at a bit of a loss as to what to do. Is there an alternative? I've read somewhere that likelihoods aren't good for quasi model, but are there any other options?

Comment: Some similar questions:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/273580/inference-for-quasibinomial-glm-with-lasso-penalty-using-selectiveinference-pack    Here: for more information:  https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pscl/vignettes/countreg.pdf

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your response variable is produced by taking the fraction of $a \textrm{ and } b$, $\{a,b\} \in \mathbb{R} \mid \{a,b\} > 0$ (i.e $a$ and $b$ are non-zero, positive, continuous), then it is reasonable to model it as being distributed according to the [Beta distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution). In such case you should perform a beta regression, implemented in the [`betareg`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/betareg/betareg.pdf) package in R. You can then compare your models with `stats::AIC`.

If $a$ represents counts and $b$ trials, you should rather use a logistic regression which uses the binomial distribution as a model. Using the quasi-binomial distribution as a model is useful if your data exhibit more (or less) variance than that expected from a binomial model. If you choose to use a quasi-binomial model, the package [`AICcmodavg`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/AICcmodavg/AICcmodavg.pdf) can provide you with the quasilikelihood counterpart of AIC. However you should proceed with caution as this metric may be too sensitive with departures from the model ([Wang et al. 2015](http://sahirbhatnagar.com/assets/pdf/Wang_et_al-2015-Stat.pdf)).

---

For more information on beta vs logistic regression see:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/29042/97671

For more discussion on when to use a quasi-binomial vs a binomial model see:
[What is quasi-binomial distribution (in the context of GLM)?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/91724/what-is-quasi-binomial-distribution-in-the-context-of-glm)

<sub>**Reference**:

Wang, Y., Murphy, O., Turgeon, M., Wang, Z., Bhatnagar, S. R., Schulz, J., and Moodie, E. E. M. (2015)

The perils of quasi-likelihood information criteria. *STAT*, **4**: 246–254. [10.1002/sta4.95](http://sahirbhatnagar.com/assets/pdf/Wang_et_al-2015-Stat.pdf)</sub>